# How set OnPLatform value of "nothing"

Tags: xamarin.forms

I see threads about default values for OnPlatform, but I don't want a default value, I want a value of "nothing."

Here is my code, with a ToolbarItem for UWP and "nothing" for Android. Unfortunately, it throws an exception. How do I code an On Platform value of "nothing"? I can get rid of the exception by coding `<ToolbarItem Text=""/>` but it takes up Toolbar real estate that gets in the way of other controls.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ToolbarItem">
        <On Platform="UWP">
            <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="MyIcon.png"/>
        </On>
        <On Platform="Android">
        </On>
    </OnPlatform>
    ...
```

Comment: just don't include Android

Comment: That also gives an exception. It appears you have to include Android or Default.

Comment: FYI other things that don't work: omitting both Text= and Icon (still takes up same amount of space); IsEnabled=False (exception, property is read-only); WidthRequest=0 (no such property); IsVisible=False (no such property)

Comment: I guess one answer might be to do it in code? this.ToolBarItems.Insert(0, new ToolbarItem(...));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you cannot do this in XAML. OnPlatform must provide a TypeArguments object for each platform on which it executes, or an exception will be thrown. Seems to me like a shortcoming in the XAML design, but no one asked me.

The solution, and in fewer lines of code than the XAML above, is in the page constructor:

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP)
{
    ToolbarItem tbi = new ToolbarItem();
    tbi.IconImageSource = "MyIcon.png";
    this.ToolbarItems.Insert(0, tbi);
}
```

You could vary the 0 in the Insert depending on where you wanted the ToolbarItem to appear (untested). I wanted it first of the ToolbarItems, hence 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code below:

```
 <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ToolbarItem">
        <On Platform="UWP">
            <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="MyIcon.png"/>
        </On>
        <On Platform="Android">
            <ToolbarItem IconImageSource=""></ToolbarItem>
        </On>
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: Same problem as Text= or for that matter simply <ToolbarItem/>. Takes up (wastes) real estate on the Toolbar and therefore screws up the positioning of other controls. I will do it in code and post the full solution here later today.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `ToolbarItem` in XAML `ResourceDictionary` (e.g. in `<ContentPage.Resources>`):

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <OnPlatform x:Key="toolbarItem" x:TypeArguments="ToolbarItem">
    <On Platform="iOS">
      <ToolbarItem
        ...
    
    <On Platform="UWP">
      <ToolbarItem
        ...

    <!-- Android: No ToolbarItem -->
```

Add it in the code behind page constructor using the resource key "toolbarItem":

```
InitializeComponent();
...

if (Resources.TryGetValue(key: "toolbarItem", out object value) &&
    value is OnPlatform<ToolbarItem> onPlatform)
{
  IEnumerable<ToolbarItem> items = GetElement(onPlatform);

  if (items.Any() && 
      items.FirstOrDefault() is ToolbarItem toolbarItem)
  {
    ToolbarItems.Add(toolbarItem);
```

`GetElement` example implementation:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetElement<T>(OnPlatform<T> onPlatform) where T : Element
{
    foreach (var platforms in onPlatform.Platforms)
    {
        foreach (string platform in platforms.Platform)
        {
            if (platform == Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                yield return platforms.Value as T;
            }
        }
    }
}
```